# Magento Admin Disabling Guest check outs

Tags: magento

I'm trying to disable guest check-outs on my company's web store. Every site I've researched tells me to go to the System tab, however, I do not have a system tab on my dashboard. Can anyone tell me how to find this or how to add it or why I don't have it?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a programming-related Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com/ instead?

Answer (score 1):

You may not be having **access** to `System > Configuration` in Magento admin if the Administrator of site who given access to you has disabled this resource for you.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 0):

Login to Admin Panel of Magento then go to System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Checkout.

Here you can restrict guest users to checkout.
[image]

Comment: Lindsey said she do not have system tab in the dashboard. She might not be given access to this resource using roles.